# Determining if and possibly retrieving a Twilio incoming MMS attachment that has an unsupported content type

Tags: php, twilio

Using the Twilio PHP API, I'm trying to account for unsupported attachments (specifically "text/x-vCard", as sent by Android/Google Fi). When I receive the $_POST vars in my code, they look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [ToCountry] => US
    [ToState] => NJ
    [SmsMessageSid] => <sms-message-id>
    [NumMedia] => 0 
    [ToCity] => MERCHANTVILLE
    [FromZip] => 08401
    [SmsSid] => <sms-sid>
    [FromState] => NJ
    [SmsStatus] => received
    [FromCity] => <from-city> 
    [Body] => This is the body of the message.
    [FromCountry] => US
    [To] => +xxxxxxxxxxx
    [ToZip] => xxxxx
    [AddOns] => {"status":"successful","message":null,"code":null,"results":{}}
    [NumSegments] => 1 
    [MessageSid] => <message-sid>
    [AccountSid] => <account-sid>
    [From] => +xxxxxxxxxxx
    [ApiVersion] => 2010-04-01
)
```

As you can see, there is no evidence of any error or warning that an unsupported file type has been sent. I need to either

- Reply to the sender that the attachment is unsupported, or
- Find the saved attachment on Twilio and forward it.

I suspect that the attachment IS saved on Twilio, because when I use the `$twilio->messages('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')->fetch()`, I get a whole lot more info, including:

```
[subresourceUris] => Array (
    [media] => /2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Media.json
))
```

I don't see a documented way to retrieve the resource using PHP, so I'm stuck. I've tried:

```
$media = $twilio->messages("MMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                ->media("MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                ->fetch();
```

This returns some items, but they are similar to the `->fetch()` return and I don't see anything that will help me download or read the media.

Comment: No Twilio evangelists out there? Do you need more information? I can supply whatever you need. I've been going back and forth on this issue with Twilio support for over a week now and they can't seem to understand the problem.

From what I understand, an attachment with an unsupported content-type should still be stored, as long as it's under 5 meg, no?

Comment: Twilio evangelist here. Been on the road so not had the chance to check in on SO recently. Can you send me the ticket number you had with support so I can check on that conversation too and hopefully answer you if they haven't managed to yet. My email is philnash@twilio.com.

Comment: Phil, I sent the info you requested yesterday -- thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after working with Twilio tech support for two weeks, I've learned that Twilio simply drops an attachment with an unsupported mime type.

As to how to get alerted to the error, there is no documented way that I could find from the Twilio docs or working with tech support, but I found a work-around that seems to do the job for now. Here's what I do:

1. Twilio sends me the incoming message to `incoming.php` on my server.
2. I get the attachment count using `$_POST['NumMedia']`.
3. Using `$_POST['SmsMessageSid']`, I query Twilio to retrieve the message stored on the server:

   ```
   $msg = $client->messages($_POST['SmsMessageSid'])->fetch();
   ```
4. I check the `$msg->numMedia` value. If it's greater than the `$_POST['NumMedia']` value, I know an attachment has been dropped.
5. If the numbers don't match, I shoot off a reply text to the sender letting them know an attachment was dropped.

I've asked Twilio support to send a note to the developers to add x-vcard as a supported type, since a LARGE number of Android phones still use it.

Thank you to [@philnash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28376/philnash) for help with the problem.